# connect to mssql with pgloader

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I'm trying to convert some data from MS SQL Server to Postgres from a Windows 10 WSL partition.

From the Ubuntu prompt on WSL, I can run the following with no issue:

```
~$ sqlcmd -C -S tcp:localhost,1432 -U myuser -P mypass -d mydb -Q "SELECT TOP 5 ID FROM dbo.Users;";
ID
------------------------------------
0D6A48CD-0FD9-254B-D82A-0243C5D0FDB4
472C0D72-DC6A-B6F7-D762-0388AC9634BC
040272A4-A196-11E4-8B84-06A1AF693EE3
F16631B1-A19B-11E4-8B84-06A1AF693EE3
4E4213D6-A1A1-11E4-8B84-06A1AF693EE3
```

Note the use of the `-C` flag to disable SSL-- without that flag set I can't connect.

When I attempt to do the same connect string with `pgloader` it fails with an `unknown reason`. I suspect it's an SSL issue again, though I am using the `--no-ssl-cert-verification` option, but I'm not sure what next steps I can take to continue debugging:

```
~$ pgloader --no-ssl-cert-verification --debug --verbose mssql://myuser:mypass@localhost:1432/mydb pgsql://myuser:mypass@localhost/mydb
pgloader version 3.6.1
sb-impl::*default-external-format* :UTF-8
tmpdir: #P"/tmp/pgloader/"
2023-08-31T22:22:18.007000Z NOTICE Starting pgloader, log system is ready.
2023-08-31T22:22:18.012000Z INFO Starting monitor
2023-08-31T22:22:18.014000Z LOG pgloader version "3.6.1"
2023-08-31T22:22:18.014000Z INFO     SOURCE: "mssql://myuser:mypass@localhost:1432/mydb"
2023-08-31T22:22:18.014000Z INFO SOURCE URI: #<PGLOADER.SOURCE.MSSQL:MSSQL-CONNECTION mssql://myuser@localhost:1432/mydb {1005D40C63}>
2023-08-31T22:22:18.014000Z INFO     TARGET: "pgsql://myuser:mypass@localhost/mydb"
2023-08-31T22:22:18.015000Z INFO TARGET URI: #<PGLOADER.PGSQL:PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://myuser@localhost:5432/mydb {1005EDB3C3}>
2023-08-31T22:22:18.015000Z DEBUG LOAD DATA FROM #<PGLOADER.SOURCE.MSSQL:MSSQL-CONNECTION mssql://myuser@localhost:1432/mydb {1005D40C63}>
2023-08-31T22:22:18.032000Z DEBUG CONNECTED TO #<PGLOADER.PGSQL:PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://myuser@localhost:5432/mydb {1005EDB3C3}>
2023-08-31T22:22:18.032000Z DEBUG SET client_encoding TO 'utf8'
2023-08-31T22:22:18.033000Z DEBUG SET application_name TO 'pgloader'
2023-08-31T22:22:18.043000Z LOG Migrating from #<MSSQL-CONNECTION mssql://myuser@localhost:1432/mydb {1005D40C63}>
2023-08-31T22:22:18.043000Z LOG Migrating into #<PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://myuser@localhost:5432/mydb {1005EDB3C3}>
KABOOM!
FATAL error: Failed to connect to mssql at "localhost" (port 1432) as user "myuser": Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.
Date/time: 2023-08-31-15:22An unhandled error condition has been signalled:
                            Failed to connect to mssql at "localhost" (port 1432) as user "myuser": Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.


Backtrace for: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10006205B3}>
0: (TRIVIAL-BACKTRACE:PRINT-BACKTRACE-TO-STREAM #<SB-IMPL::STRING-OUTPUT-STREAM {1006D540E3}>)
1: (TRIVIAL-BACKTRACE:PRINT-BACKTRACE #<PGLOADER.CONNECTION:DB-CONNECTION-ERROR {1006D53F53}> :OUTPUT NIL :IF-EXISTS :APPEND :VERBOSE NIL)
2: ((FLET "H0" :IN PGLOADER::MAIN) #<PGLOADER.CONNECTION:DB-CONNECTION-ERROR {1006D53F53}>)
3: (SB-KERNEL::%SIGNAL #<PGLOADER.CONNECTION:DB-CONNECTION-ERROR {1006D53F53}>)
4: (ERROR PGLOADER.CONNECTION:DB-CONNECTION-ERROR :MESG "Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason." :TYPE "mssql" :HOST "localhost" :PORT 1432 :USER "myuser")
5: ((:METHOD PGLOADER.SOURCES:FETCH-METADATA (PGLOADER.SOURCE.MSSQL:COPY-MSSQL PGLOADER.CATALOG:CATALOG)) #<PGLOADER.SOURCE.MSSQL:COPY-MSSQL {100699BA03}> #S(PGLOADER.CATALOG:CATALOG :NAME "mydb" :SCHEMA-LIST NIL :TYPES-WITHOUT-BTREE NIL :DISTRIBUTION-RULES NIL) :MATERIALIZE-VIEWS NIL :ONLY-TABLES #<unused argument> :CREATE-INDEXES T :FOREIGN-KEYS T :INCLUDING NIL :EXCLUDING NIL) [fast-method]
6: ((:METHOD PGLOADER.LOAD:COPY-DATABASE (PGLOADER.SOURCES:DB-COPY)) #<PGLOADER.SOURCE.MSSQL:COPY-MSSQL {100699BA03}> :ON-ERROR-STOP T :WORKER-COUNT 4 :CONCURRENCY 1 :MULTIPLE-READERS NIL :MAX-PARALLEL-CREATE-INDEX NIL :TRUNCATE NIL :DISABLE-TRIGGERS NIL :DATA-ONLY NIL :SCHEMA-ONLY NIL :CREATE-SCHEMAS T :CREATE-TABLES T :INCLUDE-DROP T :DROP-SCHEMA NIL :CREATE-INDEXES T :INDEX-NAMES :UNIQUIFY :RESET-SEQUENCES T :FOREIGN-KEYS T :REINDEX NIL :AFTER-SCHEMA NIL :DISTRIBUTE NIL :ONLY-TABLES NIL :INCLUDING NIL :EXCLUDING NIL :SET-TABLE-OIDS T :ALTER-TABLE NIL :ALTER-SCHEMA NIL :MATERIALIZE-VIEWS NIL) [fast-method]
7: ((LAMBDA ()))
8: (PGLOADER:RUN-COMMANDS (LAMBDA NIL (LET ((*MUFFLED-WARNINGS* (QUOTE STYLE-WARNING))) (CFFI:LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY (QUOTE MSSQL::SYBDB))) (LET* ((PGLOADER.SOURCES:*DEFAULT-CAST-RULES* (QUOTE ((:SOURCE (:TYPE "char") :TARGET (:TYPE #1="text" :DROP-TYPEMOD T)) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "nchar") :TARGET (:TYPE #1# :DROP-TYPEMOD T)) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "varchar") :TARGET (:TYPE #1# :DROP-TYPEMOD T)) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "nvarchar") :TARGET (:TYPE #1# :DROP-TYPEMOD T)) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "ntext") :TARGET (:TYPE #1# :DROP-TYPEMOD T)) (:SOURCE (:TYPE #2="xml") :TARGET (:TYPE #2# :DROP-TYPEMOD T)) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "int" :AUTO-INCREMENT T) :TARGET (:TYPE "bigserial" :DROP-DEFAULT T)) (:SOURCE (:TYPE #3="tinyint") :TARGET (:TYPE "smallint")) (:SOURCE (:TYPE #3# :AUTO-INCREMENT T) :TARGET (:TYPE "serial")) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "bit") :TARGET (:TYPE "boolean") :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::SQL-SERVER-BIT-TO-BOOLEAN) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "uniqueidentifier") :TARGET (:TYPE "uuid") :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::SQL-SERVER-UNIQUEIDENTIFIER-TO-UUID) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "hierarchyid") :TARGET (:TYPE #4="bytea") :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::BYTE-VECTOR-TO-BYTEA) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "geography") :TARGET (:TYPE #4#) :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::BYTE-VECTOR-TO-BYTEA) (:SOURCE (:TYPE #5="float") :TARGET (:TYPE #5#) :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::FLOAT-TO-STRING) (:SOURCE (:TYPE #6="real") :TARGET (:TYPE #6#) :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::FLOAT-TO-STRING) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "double") :TARGET (:TYPE "double precision") :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::FLOAT-TO-STRING) (:SOURCE (:TYPE #7="numeric") :TARGET (:TYPE #7#) :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::FLOAT-TO-STRING) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "decimal") :TARGET (:TYPE #7#) :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::FLOAT-TO-STRING) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "money") :TARGET (:TYPE #7#) :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::FLOAT-TO-STRING) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "smallmoney") :TARGET (:TYPE #7#) :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::FLOAT-TO-STRING) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "binary") :TARGET (:TYPE #4#) :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::BYTE-VECTOR-TO-BYTEA) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "image") :TARGET (:TYPE #4#) :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::BYTE-VECTOR-TO-BYTEA) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "varbinary") :TARGET (:TYPE #4#) :USING PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::BYTE-VECTOR-TO-BYTEA) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "smalldatetime") :TARGET (:TYPE #8="timestamptz")) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "datetime") :TARGET (:TYPE #8#)) (:SOURCE (:TYPE "datetime2") :TARGET (:TYPE #8#))))) (PGLOADER.SOURCES:*CAST-RULES* (QUOTE NIL)) (PGLOADER.PARAMS:*MSSQL-SETTINGS* (QUOTE NIL)) (PGLOADER.PARAMS:ON-ERROR-STOP (GETF (QUOTE NIL) :ON-ERROR-STOP T)) (PGLOADER.PARAMS:*PG-SETTINGS* (PGLOADER.PGSQL:SANITIZE-USER-GUCS (QUOTE NIL))) (PGLOADER.PARAMS:*PGSQL-RESERVED-KEYWORDS* (PGLOADER.PGSQL:LIST-RESERVED-KEYWORDS #9=#<PGLOADER.PGSQL:PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://myuser@localhost:5432/mydb {1005EDB3C3}>)) (PGLOADER.PARAMS:*COPY-BATCH-ROWS* (OR NIL PGLOADER.PARAMS:*COPY-BATCH-ROWS*)) (PGLOADER.PARAMS:*COPY-BATCH-SIZE* (OR NIL PGLOADER.PARAMS:*COPY-BATCH-SIZE*)) (PGLOADER.PARAMS:*PREFETCH-ROWS* (OR NIL PGLOADER.PARAMS:*PREFETCH-ROWS*)) (PGLOADER.PARAMS:*ROWS-PER-RANGE* (OR NIL PGLOADER.PARAMS:*ROWS-PER-RANGE*)) (PGLOADER.PARAMS:*IDENTIFIER-CASE* (OR NIL PGLOADER.PARAMS:*IDENTIFIER-CASE*)) (PGLOADER.PARSER::SOURCE (MAKE-INSTANCE (QUOTE PGLOADER.SOURCE.MSSQL:COPY-MSSQL) :TARGET-DB #9# :SOURCE-DB #<PGLOADER.SOURCE.MSSQL:MSSQL-CONNECTION mssql://myuser@localhost:1432/mydb {1005D40C63}>))) NIL (PGLOADER.LOAD:COPY-DATABASE PGLOADER.PARSER::SOURCE :INCLUDING (QUOTE NIL) :EXCLUDING (QUOTE NIL) :ALTER-SCHEMA (QUOTE NIL) :ALTER-TABLE (QUOTE NIL) :MATERIALIZE-VIEWS (QUOTE NIL) :DISTRIBUTE (QUOTE NIL) :SET-TABLE-OIDS T :ON-ERROR-STOP PGLOADER.PARAMS:ON-ERROR-STOP) NIL)) :START-LOGGER NIL :FLUSH-SUMMARY T :SUMMARY NIL :LOG-FILENAME NIL :LOG-MIN-MESSAGES NIL :CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES NIL)
9: (PGLOADER:LOAD-DATA :FROM #<PGLOADER.SOURCE.MSSQL:MSSQL-CONNECTION mssql://myuser@localhost:1432/mydb {1005D40C63}> :INTO #<PGLOADER.PGSQL:PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://myuser@localhost:5432/mydb {1005EDB3C3}> :ENCODING :UTF-8 :FIELDS NIL :TARGET-TABLE-NAME NIL :OPTIONS NIL :GUCS NIL :CASTS NIL :BEFORE NIL :AFTER NIL :START-LOGGER NIL :FLUSH-SUMMARY T)
10: (PGLOADER.MONITOR::CALL-WITH-MONITOR #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN PGLOADER::MAIN) {10059F0D9B}>)
11: (PGLOADER::MAIN ("pgloader" "--no-ssl-cert-verification" "--debug" "--verbose" "mssql://myuser:mypass@localhost:1432/mydb" "pgsql://myuser:mypass@localhost/mydb"))
12: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN "/build/pgloader-6o2gux/pgloader-3.6.1/dumper-2SKVI5f7.lisp"))
13: ((FLET SB-UNIX::BODY :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))
14: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-14" :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))
15: ((LABELS SB-IMPL::RESTART-LISP :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))



2023-08-31T22:22:18.053000Z INFO Stopping monitor
```

Comment: -C is "Trust Server Certificate", not disable TLS.  Which version of SQL Server are you trying to connect to?  Do you get any error messages in the SQL Server ERRORLOG?